# Preventing form re-submission without causing troubles with cookies

Tags: php, cookies

I have searched online for some solutions to avoid the resubmission of the form when a user hits the back button, and I have found few solutions similar to the below:

```
header("Cache-Control: no cache");
session_cache_limiter("private_no_expire");
```

this works very well with me, however, I realized later that this would prevent setting cookies expiry date, thus my users would be able to access pages even after logging out!.

Can you please advise some other solution that pages don't ask to resubmit forms, however, don't affect the ability to delete (expire) cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting to another page would be the possible solution. Or you can also redirect to same page, I think it won't ask to send same data again.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // your code here
    // after from submission you can redirect to same or another page
    header("Location:form.php");

}
```

Comment: May I please elaborate a bit more, the page that I have has self-posting to show search results, however when the user clicks on one of those results another page of course will open, now the problem is when the user hits back button to return to the same page, here the page would ask to resubmit, this is what I want to prevent.

Comment: When you use self-redirecting after the form submission browser thinks the previous action as a get request. So, if you hit F5 or click back button it won't say to resubmit.